# IE doesn't generate XMLHttpRequest.upload.onprogress events properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, upload, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I send 4 POST requests in parallel. Normal browsers like Chrome and Firefox generate upload onprogress events evenly. 
But IE (tested on versions 10 and 11) generates events only when requests are finished or aborted or on half of upload. My code looks like this:

```
function XHRUpload(/* ... */) {
    //...
    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
    this.request.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        console.log(e.loaded, e.total);
    };
    this.request.onerror = function(e, msg) {
        //...
    };
    this.request.ontimeout = function(e, msg) {
        //...
    };
    this.request.open('POST', this.url, true);
    this.request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8');
}

XHRUpload.prototype.upload = function() {
    this.request.send(this.options.data);
};

XHRUpload.prototype.abort = function() {
    this.request.abort();
};
```

Comment: what version of IE?

Comment: @epascarello I tested on versions 10 and 11. Both have the same issue.